# AJAX возвращает ошибку с кодом 500

Tags: php, ajax

Есть форма, из неё аяксом передаются данные на скрипт авторизации, и этот же скрипт должен вернуть в соответствии с результатом определенный ответ.

На локалке всё грузилось нормально - всё отлично возвращалось, при размещении на сервер форма перестала работать, консоль говорит - ошибка 500 Server Internal Error.

Сам аякс:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#mainform').submit(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var m_method = $(this).attr('method');

            var m_action = $(this).attr('action');

            var m_data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: m_method,
                url: m_action,
                data: m_data,
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#mainform').html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Форма:

```
<form action="t/a.php" method="post" id="mainform">
    <h1 class="header-line">Авторизация</h1>
    <ul class="feature-blocks">
        <li>Логин:</li>
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="login">
        </li>
        <li>Пароль:</li>
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="pass">
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="submit">Войти</button>
        </li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li>Нет аккаунта? <a href="#">Зарегестрируй!</a> 
</form>
```

Кто сталкивался подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ошибка 500 Server Internal Error

Откройте и читайте лог бекенда.

Comment: Спасибо, нашёл причину. 
Забыл поставить в обработчике точку с запятой.